# Generate an enum dynamically from file with intellisense support

Tags: c#, roslyn

I heard lots about Roslyn, and I just thought is it possible to generate code dynamically from an xml file so that for the developer it will be transparent and he could enumerate the code with IntelliSense as if the code is written in the project.

I am writing a framework with a lot of customization done via config files, and would really like to use such feature if it's possible.

Comment: Asking off-site resource are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Fine. Removed the question. I'd use any help provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is what F# calls [type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx) and it probably is possible to do by hacking the Roslyn compiler but I think it will be a lot of work. You may want to have a look at the related question [Could F# type providers be incorporated in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771700/could-f-type-providers-be-incorporated-in-c-sharp). Your best bet may be to use the F# type providers in a F# project and then reference this project and its types from C# projects but I can not tell if this is viable because I am lacking F# experience.

Comment: Right! That's exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately looks like it is impossible to use it now, as I'm not allowed to strict the language down to F# and the feature I wanted to use this in is major and should be accessible for any .Net language.

Comment: As stated you may be able to use type providers in a single assembly written in F# to get the types for your XML and then you can reference that assembly from any project written in any language. But you will have to try it or ask somebody else, I can not tell if it will just work, need some hacking or will not work at all.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find an article where Type Providers are used in C# from F#. And it works on my machine. So I just need to learn F# now :)