# reading into an enum from xml in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums

I currently have a project I am working on in c# that uses an enum.

At the moment it looks like this . . .

```
public enum Temp
{
    CAREA = 10,
    CAREB = 20,
    CAREC = 22,
    CARED = 35
}
```

However instead of that I would like to call the same data (as an enum) from either a .txt file or an .xml file. Either will do. This is to save a re-build every time I have to add another entry into the enum (this happens frequently) - it would be much easier to edit the .txt or .xml file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate an enum dynamically from file with intellisense support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960267/generate-an-enum-dynamically-from-file-with-intellisense-support)

Comment: Closers: It's not a dupe (the OP is not asking for Roslyn) and it's not "too broad" either.

Comment: Looks to me like the dictionary route will work for me. Many thanks to everybody for posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an enum which changes dynamically at runtime I suggest you use a Dictionary.

```
class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> tempValues = new Dictionary<string, int>() { 
        { "CAREA", 10 }, 
        { "CAREB", 20 },
        { "CAREC", 22 },
        { "CARED", 35 }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> TempValues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tempValues 
        }
    }
}
```

You still need to load the values from a file and fill them:

```
private void ReadValues(string path)
{
    foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
    {
        string[] tokens = string.Split(',');
        string key = tokens[0];
        int value = int.Parse(tokens[1]);

        // TODO: check if key does not already exist
        this.tempValues.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Your input file would need to look like this:

```
CAREA,10
CAREB,20
CAREC,22
CARED,35
```

Comment: I think this will work for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An enumeration in C# is a set of named constants. If you're dynamically generating distinct values from a data source, these values cease to be constant. It sounds like a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

use a dictionary instead:

```
var myEnums = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public void ReadIt()
{
    // Open your textfile into a streamreader
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("text_path_here.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream) // Keep reading until we get to the end
        {
            string splitMe = sr.ReadLine(); //suppose key and value are stored like "CAREA:10"
            string[] keyValuePair = splitMe.Split(new char[] { ':' }); //Split at the colons

            myEnums.Add(keyValuePair[0], (int)keyValuePair[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this. The enumeration's values (`CAREA`, `CAREB`, etc.) must be available at compile time.

What you could do, however, is provide all values in code, and parse what's supported from a plain text or XML file. You can use the following extension method for that.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the string to a specified enumeration.
/// A value specifies whether the operation is case-insensitive.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">The type of System.Enum to parse as.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The System.String value.</param>
/// <param name="ignoreCase"><c>true</c> to ignore case; <c>false</c> to regard case.</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="value"/> is <c>null</c>.</exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><paramref name="value"/> does not map to one of the named constants defined in <typeparamref name="TEnum"/>.</exception>
public static TEnum ParseAs<TEnum>(this String value, bool ignoreCase)
    where TEnum : struct
{
    return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value, ignoreCase);
}
```

Usage:

```
var enumValue = "CAREA".ParseAs<Temp>(ignoreCase: false);
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, he is not.